# Review post test

Tags: support, review

Does Super User employ review tests like these (screenshot below) or just depends on Moderators' opinions for reviewers?

I never encountered such a test on Super User.

[image]

Comment: [Further reading on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info).

Answer (score 4):

This is automatic. Review audits happen automatically and randomly to ensure review quality.

Comment: Sorry but doesn't look like an answer to my question. Maybe the answer need to be rephrased. Do these checks appear in Superuser? I have happened to review a lot of posts on Superuser and it never appeared on me once. Instead my skills were tested manually.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava sorry, I didn't notice that it was on Server Fault. Review audits are enabled on Super User, although you may or may not see one anytime soon.

Comment: (Moderators don't manually audit review actions, although if we notice a user abusing review privileges they may be contacted privately and asked to change their review habits.)

Comment: Sorry,but I'm not a moderator so I don't know how they work. I would appreciate if you can elaborate on review habit and abuse metrics. How are these metrics deduced? Let me know if this is a separate question so that I can start a new topic.

Comment: There are no specific metrics—we apply common sense. If we have to delete spam posts that have been up voted or deemed as okay from the review queue, we might check who reviewed that post.

Comment: Oh, it absolutely happens on SU, I got one the other day ;p

Comment: I got one not five minutes ago.